# Safari password saving errors

Tags: firefox, safari

Anthem.com changed their login page and it now adds a ~ to the front of the login name. This name and password is saved in Safari preferences but doesn't work when using it to log on, only the logon name without the tilde.

I've seen this on one other website. I have a ticket with Anthem but they seem to be more Windows centric. It does the same thing in Firefox but doesn't add the tilde in Opera. Anyone know what's going on?

[image: Password setting showing prepended tilde]

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, if you double click on the username value, you can change it.
Then the new value will be used in the login form.